# jQuery Mobile content height issue with iOS 7

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, mobile, ios7

I have created a web app using jQuery mobile 1.4.2. My layout includes a header, content and footer on a normal page.

For some reason, I am still able to scroll down page on iOS 7 safari even though all elements within the content are visible. This is causing me some issues throughout my app, and I have tried seemingly everything to fix it.

Here are some screenshots to explain what I mean:

Not scrolled: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaqV2.jpg[image: Not scrolled]

Scrolled: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VL4W.jpg[image: Scrolled]

As you can see, I am able to scroll down for no apparent reason...

I am **not** having this issue in Chrome or Safari on Mac, only in Safari mobile.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. All I had to do is **remove** the following content in the viewport meta tag:

```
height=device-height
```

Works fine now!